# Can all regression networks be reduced to one output?

Tags: neural-networks

Lets say I have a neural network that outputs two numbers. I can represent those two numbers uniquely using the Cantor pairing function. Now, this function is for natural numbers, but I think it can be easily remedied for real numbers by multiplying enough powers of 10 so that there are no digits after the decimal (in principle this would not work for say, 1/3, but in practice this decimal would have an end). This function can be generalized to n-tuples, so that n numbers can be represented uniquely by one number. This would greatly reduce number of connections. Has anything like this been implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a bijection betweeen $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \geq 1$. No, it's not a good idea to take advantage of this bijection to turn a multivariate regression problem into a univariate one, because any prior beliefs you hold about the relationship between the dependent and independent variables (perhaps that it is linear, or piecewise constant, or "simple", or that it can be well-approximated by a low-degree polynomial or spline) would be completely mangled by the bijection (which is not smooth nor continuous, and is unlikely to be mathematically "nice" in the ways you might desire).